# mongoose populate doesn't work with array of IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these two 3 models User, Product and Orders and are also has references to each other.

My Orders Schema:

```
const orderSchema = Schema({

buyerId:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
totalAmount: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "description is required"]
},
    createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
},
    items:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}]})
```

I'm trying to use populate() like this:

```
    Order.find()
    .populate('buyerId')//Reference to User Model
    .populate('items')// Reference to Product Model
    .exec(function (err, result){

        console.log(result);// RETURNS ONLY buyerId populated
        console.log(result.buyerId.name);//Successfully references to my User model and prints name
        console.log(result.items);//Prints Undefined

    })
```

You can see my console log above and what it returns is only the populated buyerId(only got the reference from my User model)

Seems like my populate('items') doesnt work at all. The items field contains array of IDs, where the IDs are those of products. I need to reference to User and Product both. I'm just following the documentation in mongoose, I don't know what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: i think lookup is better , if you want I create query

Comment: Yes can you help me with that please

Comment: If you don't put .populate('items'), does items contain a list of ids or still undefined ?
Because, then there might be something wrong with the way you add a new product inside your order, or with the models.

Comment: @jeremynac if I remove it and just leave the populate buyer Id I can reference and get the data from the User collection

Comment: Ok, if you just put ```.populate('items')```, are items populated ?

Comment: Thank you too. You made me realize I'm actually able to pulled up the data I wanted using populate, it's just I'm incorrectly printing out the arrays. Now I have two methods for joining collections in mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregate

```
Order.aggregate([
    { $match:{ user:"sample_id"
     }
    },
    {$lookup:{
        from:'users', // users collection name
        localField:'buyerId',
        foreignField:'_id',
        as:'buyerId'
    }},
    {
        $lookup:{
            from:'items', //items collection name
            localField:'items',
            foreignField:'_id',
            as:'items'
        }
    },

])
```

Comment: How do I reference to those as: fields and as: buyerId? How do I output the result? I connected .then(result) at the end of your code and console log it but just got the documents from Order collections

Comment: lookup as field put populated data as field name we defined in lookup as value of `as`, from is collection name of each schema you want populate , I don't know the collection names , so I just make query to change it as your environment

Comment: Oh I think I'm getting it now. Thank you, I'll update here.

Comment: Thank you problem solved. I've been dealing with this for hours.

Comment: May I ask one more question. How do I perform lookup if I have an ID to match with documents? Because my first scenario was find all, what if I need to find one document but still need to reference to other collections?

Comment: let me know , before lookup you want search and find specific doc by id  ?

Comment: yes that's right. I use find() before in my Order model, but since it cannot reference to User and Product I need to also use lookup. I want the same exact data as my previous scenario, it's just that I only want the order data of a specific user via ID.

Comment: you could add another stage match now I will update my answer

Comment: wow, let me try that. I never thought it's just as simple as that.

Comment: I cant pull up a result.If I got it correctly { $match:{ user:"sample_id"}, where "user" is a field in my document and "sample_id" is an ID that I pass, and it's without the qoutes right? For example my actual code is { $match:{ buyerId: userId}

Comment: yeah I forgot your schema details

Comment: I still cant pull up result given the correct schema. It gives me undefined array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237041/discussion-between-mohammad-naimi-and-quielfaulo).